# Terribly slow on Grails app

Tags: java, performance, grails, intellij-idea

The performance of grails app is terribly slow. It needs at least 5-7 seconds to load a page. Sometimes will prompt me OutOfMemory and then server error 500 for every page.

The terribly slow performance seriously affects my work and I am unable to test and develop the project in an acceptable time. I have to deal with this problem first.

I tried to:

1. Config the settings in idea64.exe.vmoptions and idea.exe.vmoptions like the settings in development handbook.
2. Config the settings of Java in Java Control Panel that I added a Runtime Parameters –Xms-4096m.
3. Config the settings of `%GRAILS_HOME%\bin\startGrails.bat, GRAILS_OPTS`.

However, this situation is not improveing.

I am using `Win7-64 bit, 8GB Ram, Intellij 13.0.2` to develop.

Please help. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Try to increase memory by using GRAILS_OPTS env variable

Comment: try to set `hibernate { show_sql = true }` in `DataSource` and see db requests

Comment: Are you doing resource hungry things like ``Domain.all.size()`` or ``Domain.all.find{}`` etc instead of solving this problems using proper queries?

Comment: @Houcem Berrayana: Thank you very very much!!! Grails is now fxxking smooth!!!! Thank you!!

Comment: @Igor Artamonov & cfrick: Thank you for your help! I just fix the problem with the first comment!

Comment: Great put it in an answer so people will get aware of it

Answer (score 2):

This is likely to be an issue with your database lookup.

Out of memory errors are probably caused by bringing back too much data (possibly filtering in the JVM instead of the database query).

Slowness is possibly caused again by bringing back too much data, or by [n+1 selects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue)

Comment: Thank you. But I think possibly not that reason, becuase my teammates use the same sources but just my computer is sooooo slow. And I found that my java in task manager only get around 1G, but my teammate get around 2-3G. Anyway, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for @Houcem Berrayana answer:
Try to increase memory by using GRAILS_OPTS env variable

I just add the environment variable GRAILS_OPTS with parameter -Xms4096, then the Grails app run so fast!!

Thank you again!